# Why PreparedStatement is much faster than Statement?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

A few days ago I had to create some processing performance tests using an in memory computing framework. So in order to do this, I needed a big data pool, which was increased incrementally given the various performance tests.

The DB was Oracle, containing a table of 22 fields. This table needed to be populated gradually from 1 mil records to 100 mil records.

For populating the table with 1 mil, I generated random test data and used java Statement to insert it into DB, and that has taken around **17 and 16 seconds minutes**. After that, I quickly realized that to populate a 100 mil records table will take forever so I tried it with PreparedStatement because I knew that is a bit faster… but the difference was so immense, **1 min and 24 seconds**, that I have started to search the web the reason behind this and found out some reasons but nothing that, in my opinion, should have this impact.

this is what I have found that might explain this difference: 
[LINK](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2012/03/why-use-preparedstatement-in-java-jdbc.html)

PreparedStatement gets pre compiled
In database and there access plan is also cached in database, which allows database to execute parametric query written using prepared statement much faster than normal query because it has less work to do. You should always try to use PreparedStatement in production JDBC code to reduce load on database. In order to get performance benefit its worth noting to use only parametrized version of sql query and not with string concatenation.

**BUT**
all the data was generated randomly, so no major caching from oracles side should be involved.

Comment: Read up about Oracle hard and soft parsing and the SGA.  There is plenty of processing cycles used for the unprepared/literal's version of the insert for hard parsing.

Comment: I recommend you trace the program before and after you make such changes. Make sure the test is fair. Then profile the resulting trace files. The results are often surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle is probably able to cache the query plan in the statement cache; per the Oracle® Database JDBC Developer's Guide [Implicit Statement Caching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/stmtcach.htm#i1071993),

> When you enable implicit Statement caching, JDBC automatically caches the prepared or callable statement when you call the `close` method of this statement object. The prepared and callable statements are cached and retrieved using standard connection object and statement object methods.
>
> Plain statements are not implicitly cached, because implicit Statement caching uses a SQL string as a key and plain statements are created without a SQL string. Therefore, implicit Statement caching applies only to the `OraclePreparedStatement` and `OracleCallableStatement` objects, which are created with a SQL string.

Comment: ok, so lets say that the query plan is cached, but I still have 22 random fields per insert, that's more then half the total insert statement...

Comment: But you aren't sending the entire query; just a query id (and your fields). Not the query *plus* the fields. Then add caching.

Comment: I don't see where the PreparedStatement is being closed. I certainly understand how implicit caching could be a big help if someone was closing and re-opening a Prepared Statement with the same SQL, but the PreparedStatement sample in the question just looks to me like a standard implementation of prepared statements (send the statement once, then send the parameters for each query). Have I missed something here?

Comment: @aurelianus The query plan is not the text of the query, it's roughly analogous to the bytecode of the query.  Re-using the plan removes the need to compile a million lines of code.